# mysql count on multiple columns from another table

Tags: mysql

I would like to get count of two columns from another table. For example, the source data is as below for the table called employee_master

```
emp_code          dept_id          sub_dept_id
1                   10                  22
2                   11                  20
3                   10                  22
4                   10                  22
5                   11                  20
6                   10                  21
```

Another source table called punching_data_table as shown below which is being joined with employee_master.

```
emp_code          present
1                   10:01 AM
2                   10:02 AM
3                   10:02 AM
4                   10:03 AM
5                   10:11 AM
6                   10:09 AM      //biometric punching time shown
```

The result is suppose to look like below.

```
dept_id     dept_count     sub_dept_id      sub_dept_count
10          4              22               3
10          4              21               1
11          2              20               2
```

Tried with following code but it doesn't count seperately for both columns even though applied group by employee_master.dept_id, employee_master.sub_dept_id. Please note that there is only 1 column common between both table that is emp_code.

```
SELECT p.emp_code
     , e.emp_code
     , COUNT(e.dept_id) dept_id_count
     , COUNT(e.sub_dept_id) sub_dept_id_count
  FROM punching_data_table p
  LEFT 
  JOIN employee_master e
    ON e.emp_code = p.emp_code
 GROUP 
    BY e.dept_id
     , e.sub_dept_id
```

Any help on the subject with explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to know to how many departments and sub-departments the employee is assigned. Is this what you ware looking for?

Comment: @gil.fernandes  Yes, I would like to count unique departments and sub-departments for employees whose finger punching exists in punching_data_table wherein only emp_code exists which is common in employee_master.

Comment: I am not clear on the logic why your output has dept 10 and sub_dept 22 on the same row and why dept 11 has sub dept 20 on the same row - is that because there is no logic? looked at overall the impression is that dept 11 only has sub dept 20 whereas in your data dept 10 has a sub dept 20 also.

Comment: @P.Salmon You correctly pointed out, I have just edited the question. I hope its much clearer now.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the punching_data_table for this query? It doesn't seem to add any information?

Comment: @Nick because the count of depts and sub depts is to be calculated for only those emp_code which are common in punching_data_table and employee_master. It successfully gets the count of dept_id if I omit the count of sub_dept_id. But I want to get the count of both, dept_id and sub_dept_id as well.

Comment: In that case, your desired output is wrong, as emp_code 6 is the only one which corresponds to dept 10, sub_dept 21, so since emp_code 6 is not in punching_data_table, dept 10, sub dept 21 should not appear in the output

Comment: @Nick now emp_code is in punching_data_table, sorry I kinda forgot to edit before.

Comment: Ok, my answer should do what you want then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a5797/1)) will give you the output that you specify:

```
SELECT em1.dept_id, em2.dept_count, em1.sub_dept_id, COUNT(em1.sub_dept_id) AS sub_dept_count
FROM employee_master em1
JOIN (SELECT dept_id, COUNT(dept_id) as dept_count 
      FROM employee_master e
      JOIN punching_data_table p
      ON e.emp_code = p.emp_code
      GROUP BY dept_id) em2
ON em1.dept_id = em2.dept_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM punching_data_table pdt WHERE pdt.emp_code = em1.emp_code)
GROUP BY dept_id, sub_dept_id
```

Output:

```
dept_id     dept_count  sub_dept_id     sub_dept_count
10          4           21              1
10          4           22              3
11          2           20              2
```

If you have a department names table e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dept_master (dept_id INT, dept_name VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO dept_master VALUES
(10, 'Department 10'),
(11, 'Department 11');
```

You can join that as well using this query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fc758/3)):

```
SELECT d.dept_name, em2.dept_count, em1.sub_dept_id, COUNT(em1.sub_dept_id) AS sub_dept_count
FROM employee_master em1
JOIN (SELECT dept_id, COUNT(dept_id) as dept_count 
      FROM employee_master e
      JOIN punching_data_table p
      ON e.emp_code = p.emp_code
      GROUP BY dept_id) em2
ON em1.dept_id = em2.dept_id
JOIN dept_master d on d.dept_id = em1.dept_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM punching_data_table pdt WHERE pdt.emp_code = em1.emp_code)
GROUP BY d.dept_id, sub_dept_id
```

And then get department names in the output instead of ids:

```
dept_name       dept_count  sub_dept_id     sub_dept_count
Department 10   4           21              1
Department 10   4           22              3
Department 11   2           20              2
```

Comment: am very much close to it, how do I show the dept_name instead of dept_id. It is stored in a different table named dept_master. Tried with Inner join and left join too but to no avail.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how you might do that.

Comment: Did my edit do what you want? If not, what is missing?

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it does exactly what I am after. I am away till tomorrow, will update soon. Thanks buddy.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy the break!

Comment: Hey Nick, sorry to bother you brother, if you can spare some time, can you look at the following query I am struggling with.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531586/unable-to-read-data-from-socket-can-not-bind-to-address-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT emp_code, MAX(dept_id_count) as dept_id_count,  MAX(sub_dept_id_count) as sub_dept_id_count
FROM
(SELECT p.emp_code  , COUNT(e.dept_id) dept_id_count, 0 as sub_dept_id_count
FROM punching_data_table p
LEFT JOIN employee_master e ON e.emp_code = p.emp_code
GROUP BY e.dept_id
UNION
SELECT p.emp_code, 0 as dept_id_count, COUNT(e.sub_dept_id) sub_dept_id_count
FROM punching_data_table p
LEFT JOIN employee_master e ON e.emp_code = p.emp_code
GROUP BY e.sub_dept_id) as subQuery
GROUP BY emp_code
```

Comment: Sorry buddy it throws error.  Every derived table must have its own alias. Even though I guess alias seems to be okay. And can you explain it too.

Comment: Firstly, you need to union 2 select queries. Then select max of them

Answer (score 0):

There are some things which are not clear in your question for example do you want distinct employees or just a occurrences  of employees, what happens if an employee does not exist in punching_data. I have made some assumptions in this answer but the crux of it is that you create 2 sub queries and join them on dept id which will force a 1 to many join

so given

```
drop table if exists employee_master,punching_data_table;

create table employee_master
(emp_code int,         dept_id  int,        sub_dept_id int);
insert into employee_master values
(1       ,            10   ,               22),
(2       ,            11   ,               20),
(3       ,            10   ,               22),
(4       ,            10   ,               22),
(5       ,            11   ,               20),
(6       ,            10   ,               21 ),
(7       ,            10   ,               21);

create table punching_data_table(emp_code int);
insert into punching_data_table values          
(1),                   
(2),                 
(3),                   
(4) ,                  
(5),
(6);

select a.dept_id,a.empcodes,s.sub_dept_id,s.empcodes from
(
select  dept_id ,count(distinct emp_code) empcodes
from employee_master
where emp_code in (select emp_code from punching_data_table)
group by dept_id
) a

join

(select dept_id , sub_dept_id, count(distinct emp_code)  empcodes
from employee_master
where emp_code in (select emp_code from punching_data_table)
group by dept_id,sub_dept_id) s
on s.dept_id = a.dept_id
order by a.dept_id,s.sub_dept_id
```

Result

```
+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
| dept_id | empcodes | sub_dept_id | empcodes |
+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
|      10 |        4 |          21 |        1 |
|      10 |        4 |          22 |        3 |
|      11 |        2 |          20 |        2 |
+---------+----------+-------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This result can be achieved without punching_data_table

```
SELECT t1.dept_id, 
       t2.sub_dept_id, 
       t1.count_dept, 
       t2.count_sub 
FROM   (SELECT dept_id, 
               sub_dept_id, 
               Count(dept_id) AS count_dept 
        FROM   employee_master 
        GROUP  BY dept_id)t1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT sub_dept_id, 
                         dept_id, 
                         Count(sub_dept_id) AS count_sub 
                  FROM   employee_master 
                  GROUP  BY sub_dept_id)t2 
              ON t1.dept_id = t2.dept_id
```